# How to compare $R^{2}$ of train and test data in a Deep Learning Neural Network Regression model?

Tags: neural-network, keras, scikit-learn, regression, score

I want to judge the goodness of my neural network regression model built using Keras Python Library. The problem is the following: from an input like (1000, 5000) so 1000 samples and each sample has 5000 numbers, I want to predict, for each sample, 4 parameters that have generated each sample (each sample has its own 4 parameters). So the output is (1000,4). The 4 paramateres are generated from a Gamma distribution (in particular from `scipy.stats.gamma.rvs = (a=3, loc=0, scale=0.1, size=4, random_state=None)`).

I splitted my data considering 5% of my data as test set and 95% as train set. So I have 50 data as test set and 950 as train set.

When I caculate the R squared for train and test data, should I consider the same number for both ? I mean that should I calculate the R squared for 50 test data and for 50 train data ?

Because if I calculate:

```
prediction_test = model.predict(X_test)
print(r2_score(y_test, prediction_test))
```

I obtain R squared equal to 0.05916183503859888. While instead if I calculate R square on *all* train data (so 950 data) using the same python code:

```
prediction_train = model.predict(X_train)
print(r2_score(y_train, prediction_train))
```

I obtain -6.939172963182204e+83 that is something of extremely bad result. While instead if I calculate the R squared on the same number of train data as the test set (so 50) I obtain 0.0751059501685121 and so a result more reasonable since the R squared of train data should be higher than the one calculated for test data because the model has been trained to recognize train data while instead the neural network has never seen test data. Is it right ?

So when comparing the train and test R squared, I should consider the same number of data for them ?

Any advice would be really appreciated and I thank you in advance.

Comment: You have four outputs. How does $R^2$ even make sense for that? // Even in a setting where $R^2$ makes sense, [the function you’re using has minimal theoretical basis and probably isn’t telling you what you want it to tell you.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/590199/how-to-motivate-the-definition-of-r2-in-sklearn-metrics-r2-score) What do you want to learn about your model by looking at $R^2?$ // There is no reason to care about the sample size, but your results are so bizarre that something odd is happening inside your code. What loss is your network minimizing?

Comment: I do not understand why $R^{2}$ does not make sense... I use it to compare the true parameters with those predicted by the model and so to understand if the model makes good predictions... Anyway thanks for the comment and I am using *mae* as loss function.

Comment: How would you calculate $R^2$ in your situation? What is the math, and why does that make sense? // Also, why look at $R^2$ if you are minimizing absolute loss?

Comment: The math is this https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html and this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination . You have the 4 parameters predicted by the model and the 4 true parameters. You apply the $R^{2}$ formula for all the test set (for example). My case is the case of a multi-output regression model so I choose to make an average between all the $R^{2}$ computed like the example in the scikit-learn page that I linked (where instead they computed a variance weighted).

Comment: Why are absolute loss function and $R^{2}$ not compatible ? @Dave

Comment: What is the equation you intend to use for $R^2$, what are you inputting into that $R^2$ equation, and why? // “Incompatible” is stronger than what I mean, but the usual $R^2$ is a measure of square loss rather than absolute loss. Your interest in minimizing absolute loss and then inspecting square loss is far from unreasonable but not the obvious way to proceed. However, I do wonder what you hope to learn from such as $R^2$ value.

Comment: The equation is $R^{2} = 1 - \frac{\sum_{i} (y_{i} - f_{i})^{2}}{\sum_{i}(y_{i} - y_{mean})^{2}}$ where $y_{i}$ is the true value and $f_{i}$ is the predicted value.

Comment: Agreed. Now what does that have to do with the four parameters you predict in your neural network?

Comment: As regards why I use this, it is because it gives an idea of the goodness of your model. If $R^{2}$ is high, it means that predicted values and true values are similar. And so the neural network has learnt to recognize the four parameters from the set of numbers given as input.

Comment: But what does any of this have to do with the four parameters you aim to fit?

Comment: Putting aside whether R squared is suitable, I also struggle to see how the R squared for 4 prediction/truth pairs got reduced to 1 value.

Comment: @Dave sorry I edited my post adjusting the numbers that were wrong. In practice, I apply the $R^{2}$ formula that I mentioned to the four parameters (there will be the true parameters and the predicted parameters). This is done, for example, 50 times because we have 4 parameters of each test sample and then the resulting $R^{2}$ is an average of all the $R^{2}$ computed for each test sample.

Comment: This approach makes no sense to me: it lacks any motivation from statistical theory, and it is giving ridiculous results. My recommendation is to stop shoehorning your model into this Python function, consider what you want to learn from your work, and post a new question either here or on the [statistics Stack](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) asking about that.

Answer (score 1):

You calculate the values and compare them, just like you would for any other metric like MSE. Note, however, that the usual Python implementation of $R^2$ [has poor theoretical motivation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/590199/how-to-motivate-the-definition-of-r2-in-sklearn-metrics-r2-score) and probably does not tell you what you want it to tell you. (It certainly doesn’t tell me what I want it to tell me.)

Your strange results are occurring because you are trying to shoehorn an unusual problem into an inappropriate $R^2$ performance metric. If you use $R^2$ in a more reasonable setting, the results will make more sense.

Comment: Thanks @Dave for your attention but I do not understand why $R^{2}$ in this context is inappropriate to use . If you look at the scikit-learn page there is also an example of application of $R^{2}$ to a case similar to mine (i.e. multi-output regression model) but they use as multioutput parameter the 'variance_weighted' instead of what I was using here that was ‘uniform_average’.

Comment: Now applying 'variance_weighted' as multi-output parameter to my data I obtain reasonable results... like $R^{2}_{test}=0.17$ and $R^{2}_{train}=0.23$ (by using 50 data to compute $R^{2}_{test}$ and all train data to compute $R^{2}_{train}$)

Comment: Maybe this is more suitable for my case ? Anyway now I read the post you linked.

Comment: so do you suggest to consider something like the MAE as a metrics of the goodness of my model in my "unusual" regression problem ?

Comment: I suggest thinking about what you’re trying to do and asking about appropriate ways to evaluate the performance of a model. Something like $R^2$ can make sense for a regression with multiple outputs, but your description seems to suggest a different kind of modeling approach than multivariate regression, more like estimating the conditional mean and conditional variance than estimating the conditional multivariate mean.